# OleDbConnection Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection

I created a class that execute OleDbConnection with a method and return this connection:

```
public class ConnectDB
    {
        public static OleDbConnection getConStr() {

            return OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.MapPath("Users.accdb") + ";Persist Security Info=False");       
        }
    }
```

but I got an error in Server.MapPath ErrorMessage:The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context.
How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably using this code in a `class library`.

`Server` is an ASP.NET object, and you can access it inside an aspx page only or a Control-derived class.

try this:

```
 public class ConnectDB
 {
    public static OleDbConnection getConStr() {

        return OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="  +   HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Users.accdb") + ";Persist Security Info=False");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only `Server.MapPath` as follows:

```
public class ConnectDB
    {
        public static OleDbConnection getConStr() {

            return OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="  +   Server.MapPath("Users.accdb") + ";Persist Security Info=False");       
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.